# How to hide the accordion button if there is no TEXT/CONTENT in the <p> </p>?

Tags: javascript, html

I have declared a button class 'accordion', and added a (+) and (-) icon to the left of the accordion button. However, I would like the the buttons to be hidden from the webpage if there is no content in the `<p> </p>`. Any help would be appreciated!:

### HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

 <body>

   <h2>Accordion</h2>


 <button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion"></button>
<div class="panel">
  <p></p>
</div>

 <script src= "Accordion.js" ></script>

 </body>

 </html>
```

### Javascript

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  }
}
```

// Tried this but it isn't working so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(".accordion").text().trim() ) {
        $("accordion").show();
    } else {
        $("accordion").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement is truthy when there is no text ("" is considered truthy in javascript).

Also, you need to iterate the JQuery set and check for existence of text in each element of the set. If you want to hide the panel and button based on the `p` elements not having any text in them then you have to get a collection of those first, iterate through them and if there is no text then get the parent div panel and then the accordion button (as the previous sibling of the div panel) and hide them:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $pElems = $("p");
  $pElems.each(function(index){
    if($pElems.eq(index).text().trim() === "") {
      var $parentPanel = $pElems.eq(index).parent(".panel");
      $parentPanel.hide();
      if ($parentPanel.length > 0) {
        $parentPanel.prev(".accordion").hide();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response! However, I just tried that and it didn't work

Comment: Yeap I missed a couple of things... sorry about that. My updated answer should work.

Comment: Unfortunately, the accordion bar is still showing up even thought the content  is empty.

Comment: Your JQuery code was checking for text in the buttons and only hiding the buttons. Re-reading your question sounds like you want to hide based on the `p` tags not having any text in them. That's a little more complicated but my updated answer should point you in the right direction on how to go about it.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.panel:has(p:empty)').prev('.accordion').hide();
```